# Unable to Start 32 bit RCP Application in 64 bit Windows Machine

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, 32bit-64bit

I have one RCP application. Which is 32 bit. I Installed that application on Windows Server 2008 which is of 64 bit. This application runs fine on that. But I had another machine with same configuration, But when I ran the same application, it generated the below logs:-

```html
!SESSION 2014-11-27 18:08:13.263 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_31
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -clean

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.configurator 0 0 2014-11-27 18:08:14.745
!MESSAGE Unable to access file "<Installation_Path>\AppName_3.0.0\plugins\org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui_old\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.177
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench (139).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin for bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench is invalid
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:146)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:980)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:265)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:400)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:111)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:427)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:193)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:441)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:397)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:385)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:165)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:554)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:524)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:455)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:443)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:423)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:193)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:444)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:397)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:385)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:313)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:227)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:139)
 at orgorg.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin for bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench is invalid
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:146)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:980)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:265)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:400)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:111)
 ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:141)
 ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:481)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:397)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:385)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 ... 78 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/ui/plugin/AbstractUIPlugin
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:165)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:554)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:524)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:455)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:443)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:423)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:193)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:444)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:397)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:385)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:313)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:227)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:139)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:980)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:265)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:400)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:111)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:427)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:193)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:444)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:397)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:385)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:313)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:227)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1274)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:160)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:867)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:51)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:188)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:549)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:504)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1236)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1212)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(Unknown Source)
 at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench (139).
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:125)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:427)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:193)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:441)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:397)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:385)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 ... 58 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin for bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench is invalid
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:146)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:980)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:265)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:400)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:111)
 ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:141)
 ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:481)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:397)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:385)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 ... 78 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.208
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in com.rcp.abc.ER was unable to load class com.rcp.abc.er.Application.
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:180)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:162)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:867)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:51)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:188)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:549)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:504)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1236)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1212)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(Unknown Source)
 at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle com.rcp.abc.ER (5).
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:125)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:427)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:193)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:444)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:397)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:385)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:313)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:227)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1274)
 at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:160)
 ... 22 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator com.rcp.abc.er.Activator for bundle com.rcp.abc.ER is invalid
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:146)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:980)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:265)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:400)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:111)
 ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/ui/plugin/AbstractUIPlugin
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:165)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:554)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:524)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:455)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass_LockClassLoader(ClasspathManager.java:443)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:423)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:193)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:444)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:397)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:385)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:313)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:227)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:139)
 ... 39 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench (139).
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:125)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:427)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:193)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:33)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:441)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:397)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:385)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 ... 58 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin for bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench is invalid
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:146)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:980)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:265)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:400)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:111)
 ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:141)
 ... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:481)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:397)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:385)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 ... 78 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.239
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.239
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.ui_3.4.0.v20080603-2000.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.239
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.search_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.239
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.render_old/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.render 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.239
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui_[1.2.0,2.0.0).

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.270
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.270
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86_1.1.0.v20070510.jar [63] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.filesystem.win32.x86 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.270
!MESSAGE Platform filter did not match: (& (osgi.os=win32) (osgi.arch=x86))
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.270
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.core.net.win32.x86_1.0.0.I20080521.jar [66] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.net.win32.x86 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.270
!MESSAGE Platform filter did not match: (& (osgi.os=win32) (osgi.arch=x86))
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.270
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.0.100.v20080509-1800/ [88] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.270
!MESSAGE Platform filter did not match: (& (osgi.ws=win32) (osgi.os=win32) (osgi.arch=x86))
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.270
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.security.win32.x86_1.0.0.v20080529-1600.jar [92] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.security.win32.x86 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.270
!MESSAGE Platform filter did not match: (& (osgi.os=win32) (osgi.arch=x86))
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.270
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.render.awt_1.0.0/ [97] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.render.awt 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.270
!MESSAGE Another singleton version selected: org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.render.awt_1.4.0.v20100430-1518
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.270
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.render_old/ [100] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui.render 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.270
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.draw2d.ui_[1.2.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.270
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.ui_3.4.0.v20080603-2000.jar [112] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.270
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.search_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.270
!MESSAGE Bundle update@plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_3.3.0.v3346.jar [122] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86 2 0 2014-11-27 18:08:18.270
!MESSAGE Platform filter did not match: (& (osgi.ws=win32) (osgi.os=win32) (osgi.arch=x86))
```

Whereas the JDK I am using on both the machine is 1.6 which is of 32 bit, While JAVA_HOME and PATH is set properly.

The Difference which I found on both the machines was on the machine where it is running in Task Manager it showed me the Process as javaw *32 , Where on the machine where It Process just started and got killed there it was like javaw.

I have tried that application in various other compatibilty modes, but still showing the same msg..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in the error message, specifically the ARCH part:

```
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
```

suggests you're running a 64-bit JDK on that machine. Using that it will look for the 64-bit version of SWT, not find it, then throw the exceptions. Check the version of Java that you have installed on that machine.

Comment: Thanks Nick Wilson, for the solution.. :)